# Persistent location permissions

Tags: firebase, permissions, location, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building an action that sometimes needs the users location to find the closest bus stop to the user, but I find it very annoying that I have to ask for permission each time I would like to get the Lat and Lng. Is there anyway to store that a user has said yes to that specific permission so I do not have to keep re-prompting every time that action is opened/closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a flag in Database and based on that flag ask for permissions. Once permission is given, you can also save the location's lat and lon data. The problem that you may face is, if the device is mobile and its location is changing, then you will not be able to fetch the exact location. In the case of Google Home or Hub, it will work as it will remain indoors and hardly move. But Assistant on Mobile may require exact location information of the phone and you will not be able to provide the correct information to the user. 
So, if you are targetting static, non-moving devices, you can save a flag and location information in Database and fetch the information from that. Otherwise, you need to use the permissions every time.

Comment: Unfortunately I am targeting moving non-static devices. Thanks for the help anyway!